# How to make a link (url) within a cell of datatable using Dash

Tags: plotly-dash

I built a plotly-dash app that generates two data tables and two scatter plots. I don't have much understanding of html but I was able to get the basic functionality built using different resources. Anyhow, one thing I can't seem to get is how to make a cell entry clickable (hyperlink). I have a url in the cell and it displays fine, but I want to click on it and open it in different tab/page. I can also add the url within  tags making it presumably "clickable" however I now see the link within  tags, and still not able to click it. See the pic below for reference.
I think I might need to use dcc.link and dcc.location components but being novice I can't quite figure out how.

My app.layout has this portion for the table2. As you can see it's a simple Div component and I am posting all the table2 as is.

```
html.Div([
html.H2("Sentimental Analysis", style={'color': 'blue'}),
 html.Div('''
    Enter the phrase:'''),
dcc.Input(id='input_2_state', value='regenerative agriculture', type='text'),

         
html.Div("Choose the number of days for which the data will be collected for?"),
dcc.Dropdown(id='dropdown_2', options=[{'label': 'A Week Ago', 'value': '7d'}, {'label': ' 2 Weeks Ago', 'value': '14d'},{'label':' A Year Ago','value':'1y'}], 
             value = '7d'),   
html.Button(id='submit-button2', children='Submit'),],style={'display': 'inline-block', 'vertical-align': 'top', 'margin-left': '3vw', 'margin-top': '3vw', 'width':'5'}),

html.Div([
    html.Div(id="table2"),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph2'),], style={'display': 'inline-block', 'vertical-align': 'top','margin-left': '3vw', 'margin-top': '3vw', 'width':'5'})
```

In my app.callback I have following defined as columns of the datatable

```
columns2= [dict(name='author', id='author', type='text'),
           dict(name='preview', id='preview', type='text'),
           dict(name='score', id='score', type='text'),
           dict(name='permalink', id='permalink')]
```

And then finally I am returning table (along with figures like this)

```
 return fig1, dt.DataTable(data=df3.to_dict('rows'), columns=columns2), fig2
```

The whole code is at [github-sentiment-analysis](https://github.com/fariha23/Sentiment_Analysis_Web_Dashboard/blob/main/notebooks/Sentiment_Analysis_DashBoard_ver3.ipynb)

Could anyone please help me as to how can I make the hyperlink's hyper?

[image]